# Error trying to install NumPy and other libraries on windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, cmd, pycharm, windows-10

I've been trying to install the NumPy library on my system but it hasn't been working out. I tried installing directly from my IDE but it says error occurred when installing package ''NumPy'. Details..'. then I tried using pip method but it keeps on telling me "pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch". Please give me an advice on what to do concerning it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is very difficult to help you if you don't share any of the full errors, perhaps you could update the question with those `Details..`? (For future reference maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps and see if the problem is resolved.
1.Open CMD
2.Type 'pip install numpy' and hit enter.

It should start the installation. After you see the "Successfully Installed" message, go back to your IDLE and try importing numpy, it should work.

Comment: Doesn't he mention he got `pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch` when trying to use pip?